# QGIS Error : Could not load source layer for INPUT

Tags: raster, clip, error, geotiff-tiff

When I try to clip a layer in QGIS 3.8.1 by using the toolbox clip function, it always returns the error **Could not load source layer for INPUT XXX.tif layer not found**.
When I manually drag and drop the layer to display it, it works. 
I already changed the path to make sure it doesn't have something to do with the external HDD Im using or with letters (ä,ü,ö) in the path. 
What else could be the reason?

[image]